# Add Google Calendar events to Apple Calendar - macOS Sonoma

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, sonoma, google-sync

I have a Google Calendar from a work account, and I want the events there to show up in (sync with) my Apple calendar on Mac.

To add Google Calendar events to Apple calendar on Mac, I believe it is doable since I found an official Google help [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop), however that must be a very old one, as I found things on MacOS Sonoma are entirely different.

This is the first time I'm using MacOS Sonoma.
Can somebody help please.

Comment: Those instructions are exactly correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple instructions for OS - Sonoma are [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/get-started-iclc0d84c7fa/14.0/mac/14.0).

Simple to follow to interface with Google calendar.

[image: cal]